# Writing a Batch File (.bat) Script to run a QGIS Python Script without opening QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, bat

I have saved a python script (named as 'Task3.py'). Currently, I will open QGIS and then run this Task3.py . This python script is saved in C:\Users\Sreeraj.qgis2\processing\scripts\Task3.py .

But, I want to write a Windows Batch File (Task3.bat), such that when I run this Task3.bat file, the Task3.py will get automatically executed (even without opening QGIS). This batch file script must be saved in E:\Sreeraj\Task Global Data CONVERSION\Split\Task3.bat .

How do I write Task3.bat (so that I can run Task3.py without even opening QGIS) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
python C:\Users\Sreeraj.qgis2\processing\scripts\Task3.py
pause
```

Save this as Task3.bat in your E:\Sreeraj\Task Global Data CONVERSION\ folder. If your python PATH is set it should run your script.

Comment: After saving this as Task3.bat; when I am running this Task3.bat ;  it is showing an error (error is displayed in C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe). The error displayed is :  '' 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. ''  .

Comment: I solved the above commented error by adding the PATH to the Task3.bat . But, I am getting an error displayed as : " python.exe has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. "

Comment: I missed to include 2 lines : '' from PyQt4.QtGui import * ''   and '' app = QApplication([]) '' in Task3.py. When I added these 2 lines, the error :  " python.exe has stopped working.'' is solved. Now, batch file is running and I am getting the required outputs perfectly. Thank You for your advice.